# Too many arguments to 'Public Overloads Property SelectedTab As TabPage'

Tags: vb.net

here is my code for some Reason i keep getting this when i try

> Visual Basic Too many arguments to 'Public Overloads Proberty SelectedTab As TabPage'

```
    Dim i As Integer = 1

    If Not TabControl1.TabPages.Count = 1 Then
        TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(TabControl1.SelectedIndex)
        TabControl1.SelectedTab(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1)

        i = i - 1
    End If
```

Thanks for the help
Michael it helped my stress and head aches back then

Comment: What do you think it means?  What does Intellisense tell you when you hover over it?

Comment: TabControl1.SelectedTab is not a method, it's a property that takes a tabpage. Just set it like this....TabControl1.SelectedTab = myTab

Comment: or like this...TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabControl1.SelectedTab` is not a method, it's a property that takes a `tabpage`. Just set it like this....`TabControl1.SelectedTab = myTab`

or like this...`TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages(0)`

or for your case like this

`TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1)`

Comment: oh this old post i lost the entire project

Comment: Thanks for the help it was great I'm developing a AppOS in vb.net wpf so I don't think this will help me but I hope it will help others!